# Mysql self join for unique combinations

Tags: mysql

I have a table session as below:

```
sessionid   conversationid  agentid

SES153130074572578571   001a60f3-d95c-4434-a8c0-fabb7d815277_OD112807172056802000   igs.399760
SES15313020119321989    001a60f3-d95c-4434-a8c0-fabb7d815277_OD112807172056802000   hgs.20073
SES153130276854998136   001a60f3-d95c-4434-a8c0-fabb7d815277_OD112807172056802000   igs.100000000308235
SES153128080803552749   00803e49-0325-4bef-b133-8c5e97f2fccc_OD112706138643350000   hgs.20031
SES153128342589414965   00803e49-0325-4bef-b133-8c5e97f2fccc_OD112706138643350000   hgs.20031
SES153129466185930775   008bba3a-98fa-414a-8f99-96956513bc66_OD112757403158502000   igs.401836
SES153129612178429544   008bba3a-98fa-414a-8f99-96956513bc66_OD112757403158502000   hgs.20076
SES153129179161527928   00976601-aac7-4ec7-9e03-61cd59875650_Payment Related Queries    hgs.20071
SES153129238786010778   00976601-aac7-4ec7-9e03-61cd59875650_Payment Related Queries    igs.100000000307102
```

i want the rows where a conversationid is assigned to only one agent id (cases where one conversationid is assigned to more than one agentid would be omitted)
    i.e. my output should be as below:

```
sessionid   conversationid  agentid
SES153128080803552749   00803e49-0325-4bef-b133-8c5e97f2fccc_OD112706138643350000   hgs.20031
SES153128342589414965   00803e49-0325-4bef-b133-8c5e97f2fccc_OD112706138643350000   hgs.20031
```

Kindly help with the query

Comment: please put data in table format its so messy to look

Comment: Whenever I have a problem with unnecessarily long and completely illegible data, I like to swap it out for something simpler. It seems kinder that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sessionid,agentid,conversationid from session as S
inner join 
(
select agentid from session
group by agentid
having count(*)=1
) T
on S.agentid=T.agentid
```

Comment: Hi Zaynul, This won't work. This would give me even the entries where a conversationid is allocated to multiple agentids. However i want only those where one conversationid is allocated to only agentid though there may be several sessonids.

Comment: kindly change your expected output result

Comment: i changed my query check now please

Comment: @ZaynulAbadinTuhin This will return all rows where the agent has exactly one row in `session`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select s.sessionid, s.agentid, s.conversationid 
from session s
inner join 
(
  select conversationid 
  from session
  group by conversationid
  having count(distinct agentid) = 1
) uq
on s.conversationid = uq.conversationid
```

`uq` will contain all `conversationid` where the number of distinct agents is 1. `Join` that with the original data to get all rows for those `conversationid`.